# How to add an odd day to a time in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

How to add an odd day to a time in PHP?

Like add 1.5 day? Any idea?

When I try like 1.5 or 1,5 then it's adding 15 days.

Is there anyway to add odd day to time?

Comment: Isn't 15 an odd day? Please explain your question in breif.

Comment: I'm talking about fractional numbers. For example ONE and HALF day.

Or add 0,2 day to a time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are fractions of days, they can be converted to seconds and then added.

```
$days = 1.5;
$seconds = (int)(86400 * $days);

$dt = new Datetime('2022-04-01');

$dt->modify($seconds.' Seconds'); //add

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');
//2022-04-02 12:00
```

Also works with $days = 1.25; This then returns 2022-04-02 06:00 as a result.
Or $days = 1.1 returns 2022-04-02 02:24.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the one approach you can do first add an exact number of days(non-fractional part) and then add fractional value in hours.

For example, If you want to add 1.5 days then add 1 day and 12 hours.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 Day +12 Hours'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help!
I multiply the number of days I have by the percentage values.
For example I'm doing that operation: 5 day * 0.35 = 1.75

And after that operation, how can I add the 1,75 day to 5 day?
Maybe first convert 1,75 day to hour and then add the time as an hour value? or any other way?

Comment: But converting to hour can be also problem in that case. Because let's say I have 1,1 day. When we convert 1.1 day to hour, the result will be 26.4 hours. So we have again fractional time.

Comment: You can use both ways to add 1.75 days to 5 days. Either you may add +1day +18hours Or you can add +42 hours

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure it would be a good practise or not but 26.4 can be converted to +26Hours + 24 Minutes